# How can I read properties in init.gradle? (version 2.4.x)

Tags: gradle

I need to configure a credential in a maven repository for plugins in an `init.gradle`. I'd like to avoid having the credentials in multiple places.

So, I hoped I could put settings in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and reference them in init.gradle. That does not work, they are not defined. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Maybe read and set the properties in `init.gradle` directly.

Comment: Then I have two copies. I'm looking to have one. If the one could be in init.gradle, please write an answer with an example.